# Not able to install tensflow on Windows 7

Tags: tensorflow

I am not able to tensor flow on Windows7 machine. I searched it and found it seems to b a proxy server problem which is trying to connect to pypi.python.org. I configured it also & tried to install tensorflow, it's still not working. 
Can anyone tell me how can I install it without compromising the security?

Thanks,
Yugank Narula

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like this is happening during the `pip install tensorflow` phase and you're unable to access the file. Please try one of the following:
(Assuming CPU)

Python 3.5
`pip install https://ci.tensorflow.org/view/Release/job/release-win/lastStableBuild/M=windows,PY=35/artifact/cmake_build/tf_python/dist/tensorflow-1.2.1-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl`

Python 3.6
`pip install https://ci.tensorflow.org/view/Release/job/release-win/lastStableBuild/M=windows,PY=36/artifact/cmake_build/tf_python/dist/tensorflow-1.2.1-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl`

Comment: Is Python version >= 3.5 mandatory to install tensorflow on Windows ? At least [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tensorflow) I see that Python 2.7 version is available for Linux and Mac, but not for Windows